# Inner join with MultiIndex fails if no overlap

Tags: python, pandas

I can't get "empty" inner joins to work with a MultiIndex.  Under 0.10.1, I have:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'i1': [1, 2, 2],
    'i2': [1, 1, 2],
     'a': [10,20,30]}).set_index(['i1', 'i2'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'i1': [3, 3],
    'i2': [1, 2],
    'b': [40, 50]}).set_index(['i1', 'i2'])
d1.join(d2, how='inner')
```

which gives me

```
Exception: Cannot infer number of levels from empty list
```

Is there any good way around this? I'd like to be able to tell in advance if the intersection is empty, so I can avoid the exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [easier to ask forgiveness than permission](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp):

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'i1': [1, 2, 2], 'i2': [1, 1, 2], 'a': [10, 20, 30]}
                  ).set_index(['i1', 'i2'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'i1': [3, 3], 'i2': [1, 2], 'b': [40, 50]}).set_index(['i1', 'i2'])
try:
    d1.join(d2, how='inner')
except Exception as err:
    # Change this to however you wish to handle this case.
    print(err)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% on this, but doing an outer join and dropping the NAs is the same as an inner join. So in the case of no matching indicies, you just get an empty dataframe. If we modify your example to include one matching record, this appears to be the case:

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'i1': [1, 2, 2],
    'i2': [1, 1, 2],
    'a': [10,20,30]}).set_index(['i1', 'i2'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'i1': [1, 3],
    'i2': [1, 2],
    'b': [40, 50]}).set_index(['i1', 'i2'])
d3 = d1.join(d2, how='outer').dropna()
d4 = d1.join(d2, how='inner')
```

Which gives:

```
In [9]: d3
Out[9]: 
        a   b
i1 i2        
1  1   10  40

In [10]: d4
Out[10]: 
        a   b
i1 i2        
1  1   10  40
```

And so after the outer join + `dropna()`, you can see how many rows `d3` and go from there. Using your original example:

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'i1': [1, 2, 2],
    'i2': [1, 1, 2],
     'a': [10,20,30]}).set_index(['i1', 'i2'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'i1': [3, 3],
    'i2': [1, 2],
    'b': [40, 50]}).set_index(['i1', 'i2'])
d3 = d1.join(d2, how='outer').dropna()
print(d3.shape) # no error, shows "(0, 2)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Got his problem in for loop by merging multi index nodes from HDFstore chunk by chunk. Solved it ugly like this, might be helpful for someone else later on.

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'i1': [1, 2, 2],
    'i2': [1, 1, 2],
     'a': [10,20,30]}).set_index(['i1', 'i2'])
d2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'i1': [3, 3],
    'i2': [1, 2],
    'b': [40, 50]}).set_index(['i1', 'i2'])
for x in y:
    try:
        d3 = d1.join(d2, how='inner')
    except Exception:            
        print "no merge possible between rows, but let's continue"
        d3 = d1.join(d2, how='outer').dropna()
    if len(d3)
        print "there's a merge"
        #action
    print "fail, but still in the race"
```